# Headless factory reset Nvidia Jetson AGX Orin

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gpu

I want to reset my Nvidia Jetoson AGX Orin from a ssh conected remote desktop. given some GPU settings issues. Due to these, the Jetson does not recognize the GPU, which means does not display any video.
Headless reset is the only way.

These are the specs when writing `neofetch`
`OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS aarch64 Kernel:5.10.64-tegra Shell:bash 5.0.17 CPU:ARMv8 rev 1 (v8l) (12) @ 2.201G`

Comment: what do you mean with "factory reset"? If this is a software issue, the software running on the machine is 100% what you put on the flash memory. "Resetting" it means restoring that flash memory to whatever state you consider "original" (that isn't clear, it's not like there's only one thing you can boot).